# Using multiple currency picklist in record type or field dependencies

Tags: record-type, multi-currency, field-dependencies

I have multiple currency feature turned on. And I've added about 5 currencies. Now I'm thinking to limit the currency picklist values in record type of Account object for example. But the picklist doesn't appear when configuring the record type.

Also I want to use the currency picklist in field dependencies, but the currency picklist doesn't appear in the controlling or in the dependent field.

Is it not possible to use currency picklist in both cases? Thanks.

Comment: I got answer from the success salesforce community, basically it's not possible. And here's idea request that relate to this issue but never got approved. https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrcFAAS

Comment: Is your record type limited to just one currency? If that is the case, you can set the picklist value and make it read only.

Answer (score 1):

There is some limitations in Dependent Picklist Considerations, in my knowledge Currency field in Account should be available as a Controlling Picklist field(Since Standard fields cannot be set as a dependent picklist). Please check out this link for the limitations in picklist

https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_dependent_field_considerations.htm&language=en_US

Comment: It states "Standard picklist fields can be controlling fields but not dependent fields". It does says that "Contact Currency" and custom object currency field is not allowed. But I tried in Account object it doesn't show as well.